# Finding "spare time" in a day from within a list of events

Tags: javascript, algorithms, loops

I have a list of events which is always sorted chronologically.  The start time is always followed by the end time.  Times are strings formatted as 'HHmmss'.

```
// list of events

var events = [
    '010000',  // start
    '013000',  // end...
    '053000',
    '060000',
    '161500',
    '184500']

// desired output

var spares = [
    '000000',  // start
    '010000',  // end...
    '013000',
    '053000',
    '060000',
    '161500',
    '184500',
    '235959']
```

How can I programmatically create a new list of "spare time" from `000000` to `235959`?

PS  I'm trying to do this in Javascript, but any conceptual answer or pseudo code would be helpful too.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can do this by simply reinterpreting the first line as an end timestamp rather than a start timestamp, and so on. Or do you need something more complicated than that?

Comment: I think its more complicated because I need to avoid collisions.  Eg.  If to events are back to back, the simple looping/offset method fails and you end up with a spare event at every junction, right?  I also need the spare events to start and end at midnight, where appropriate.  So if there is no existing event which starts at midnight, I need to simulate it somehow.

Comment: Okay, can you add an example of the supposed input and output values then? It should contain at least one instance of overlapping events, so that it's clear what the difficulty is.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an implementation issue but is too old to migrate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "spare time" is defined as the time in between the events, then your list format makes it very easy to convert you list of events to a list of spare times:

1. Add midnight to both the start and end of your list
2. Go over the new list and remove any interval of less than 0 seconds (or whatever threshold you want).

With your example events, this would give you after step 1:

```
000000
010000
013000
053000
060000
161500
184500
235959
```

and after step 2:

```
000000
010000
013000
053000
060000
161500
184500
235959
```